# JSP vs XML with XSL

Tags: jsp, xslt

We are developing a Java EE web application. We want to know which is the better approach for rendering data; JSP or XML with XSL?

What are the pros and cons of each approach?

Answer (score 0):

If you already getting XML documents then use XSL otherwise I would prefer JSP. XSL has its limitation when you want to do certain complex stuff. You can still possibly achieve it but the XSL would be too complex.

In JSP world you gets lots of options as in lot of tag libraries are there which makes your life easier. JSP is also widely used so you will find skills easily and support in the community as well.